# Thread connection to web server lags 190-318/system_process E/ThrottleService

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I made class extends service and I wrote a separate thread sleeps for 1 sec

My service and Thread:

```
public class UpdaterService extends Service {
private static String TAG = UpdaterService.class.getSimpleName();
private Updater updater;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    updater = new Updater();
    updater.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "Create'd");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public synchronized int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start'd");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Destroy'd");

    super.onDestroy();
}

class Updater extends Thread {
    ArrayList<chatData> list = new ArrayList<chatData>();
    ArrayList<String> getContactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Boolean thereIsNewData = false;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String yourID = prefs.getString("KEY_USERNAME", "No login info available");
    void getData(){
        chatServiceHandler jsonParser = new chatServiceHandler();

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourID", yourID));

        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall("http://example.com/getMSG.php", contactsServiceHandler.GET, nvp);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    list.clear();
                    JSONArray contactsArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MSGhandling");

                    for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) contactsArray.get(i);
                        chatData cat = new chatData(catObj.getString("sender"), catObj.getString("receiver"),catObj.getString("msg"),catObj.getString("msgID"));
                        list.add(cat);
                        thereIsNewData = true;
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                thereIsNewData = false;
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            thereIsNewData = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                DatabaseAdapter helper = new DatabaseAdapter(UpdaterService.this);
                getData();

                if(thereIsNewData){
                    for(int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){
                        chatData messages = list.get(i);
                        Log.d(TAG, "From: "+messages.getSenderID()+" TO:"+messages.getReceiverID()+" MSG: "+messages.getMSG());
                        helper.storeMSG(messages.getSenderID() , messages.getReceiverID() , messages.getMSG() , messages.getMsgID());
                        Intent newMessage = new Intent();
                        newMessage.setAction("NEW_MESSAGE");
                        sendBroadcast(newMessage);
                    }
                    list.clear();
                    thereIsNewData = false;
                }else{

                    Log.d(TAG, "There is no new data");
                }

                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
       }
   }
}
```

It works fine for like 10 secs it loops for 10 times but after that it stops for like 30 secs and shows this error:

**LOG_CAT:**

190-318/system_process E/ThrottleService﹕ problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03

Then the same thing happen loops for 10 secs then stops for 30 more

Comment: Most likely, this error message is a symptom, while your problem is that trying to hit a server every second (especially by this roundabout mechanism of firing an Intent to service) is just not *reasonable* program behavior.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So the way I connect is wrong? is there any other way I can connect to the server every sec? How can get data instantly?